# How do I create a view with scrolling where the size of a label is unknown?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

In my iPhone application I have a table view. When user taps any row, information about that element will open.  All information comes from an XML file, size unknown; some information may contain images.

I tried to do it using a multiline label and image view, both inside an UISrollView, but I couldn't get scrolling.  And is it possible to get a pinching and zooming effect for UILabel?  And how do I add a hyperlink to text of the label?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to UIScrollView setContentSize to the actual height of the content. You can calculate it from your Label's height.

For doing all those pinching, zooming, hyperlink easily, you should just use UIWebView.